# Use pv with find -exec

Tags: find, checksum, pv

I use the following command to verify ~700 GiB of backed-up files:

```
$ find -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort > ~/checksums
```

This takes many hours, so I would like to integrate `pv` into the command to show the progress.

I could do this:

```
$ find -type f -exec pv {} + | md5sum
```

But it concatenates all of the files, resulting in only one checksum.

So how could I include `pv` and still get a text file full of checksums at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first command should not be able to run at all as you can't use a pipe in an `-exec` like that (this was apparently a typo in the [original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/495440/1)).

Instead:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort -o ~/checksums
```

or, with `pv`,

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | pv | sort -o ~/checksums
```

In both of the above, `md5sum` would be called with as many pathnames as possible in batches.  `sort` would take the output of `find` (which is the output of `md5sum`) and sort it into the given filename.  The second variation additionally inserts `pv` between the `find` and the `sort`.

You can't use `-exec pv {} | md5sum` for *individual files* as the pipe would need to be embedded in a in-line shell script that you call from `-exec` for each file.  But even the correct `-exec sh -c 'pv "$1" | md5sum' sh {} \;` would discard the filename from the generated `md5sum` output, so that can't be used either.  The `pv` utility acts like a drop-in replacement for `cat`.

Comment: I wrote the first command wrong. I'll change it.